# Problem while opening a new page from a link - It always opens in a middle of the page

Tags: html

I hope someone can help me. I have an issue with going to pages from my index page. But for some reason not all of them. The problem is that when I navigate to these pages they do not open at the top of the page, but rather open on what appears to be the same scroll position from the index at the moment. The same happens when I navigate back to the index page from the opened one. It is just a basic HTML href structure, I even tried adding ID tags to the top element and adding it to the link but no success.

So I basically just need a way to make these pages open at the top of the page, either with HTML, JS, or Jquery whatever can help.

Comment: can you please demonstrate pcs of code here for more clearity

Comment: <a href="/justgo.html">
         <div class="project p-3">
            <div class="cover cov-3"></div>
            <div class="p-info">
            <div class="project-title"><h1>JUST GO</h1></div>
           <div class="project-categ"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </a>

Here is a link that leads me to one of these pages. It is a whole div turned into a link to that page

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Don't add code in comment but update your question instead

Answer (score 0):

If i am understand your problem correctly then you need to move to top when your page load.
so in your target page that you are open write below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

using above code it just moves your scroll to top when you load your page.
try second

Comment: This is the right understanding of my question. Thank you mate. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue. Is there maybe something else I need to add for this to work?

Comment: yes you requires to add jquery for above code

Comment: when page load log printed in console window?

Answer (score -2):

To open pages in a new tab, use target="_blank" attribute.
Check out this documentation with target attribute for more clarity.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?

Comment: Thank you mate, but that is not what I am talking about. My problem is that the page that I open is not loading at the top of the page. I need it to stay on the same tab but to open at the top of the page not in the middle